# Help with simplifying a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

Could anyone help simplify this expression,
$$\dfrac{\sin^{(-1)}\left(\dfrac{\sin(90)\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}-0.25}}{\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}}}\right)}{360}-0.5\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}-0.25}
$$

It's in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\sin(90)\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}-0.25}}{\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}}}\right)}{360}-0.5\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}-0.25}
&=\dfrac{\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}-0.25}}{\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}}}\right)}{2\pi}-0.5\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}-0.25}
\qquad\text{converting to radians}\\
&=\dfrac{\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-\pi/4}\right)}{2\pi}-0.5\sqrt{\frac1{\pi}-0.25}\\
\\
&=-0.054022154...
\qquad\text{according to Wolfy}\\
\end{array}
$